# RecordsAffected returns 411 but no actual records returned

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using asp.net (VB.NET) to populate a table  using Microsoft Application Blocks (MAB) to get the data back.  When I run the stored procedure in SQL Server management, it returns one recordset of Zero records.  In MAB, the recordset returns zero records but RecordsAffected property returns 411 records.

```
Dim sqlParameters As SqlParameter() = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(connectionString, "GetList")
    sqlParameters(0).Value = UID (543435)
    sqlParameters(1).Value = Para1 (1)
    sqlDataReader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetList", sqlParameters)
```

I'm not going to show the SQL, there's no point, it returns zero records.  The RecordsAffected returned 411 records, why the discrepancy?  How can I get RecordsAffected to return zero.

Comment: Can you include the SP too?

Comment: I select a number of records and put them into a temporary table (411) and then filter the temporary table to return zero records.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of RecordsAffected is not necessarily the number of records returned.  It may refer to the number of records updated, deleted or inserted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

When you run in SSMS, it returns zero record.  The reason you see 411 is probably because 411 records are updated.  You need to go back to your SQL for details.  On the other hand, if you want to get zero, add

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Comment: Don't want to add 'SET NOCOUNT NO' because I want the number of records that are returned in the reader.  Zero if zero records, 10 if 10 records are returned in the reader.

Comment: nah... if your table has 5 records, and u select * from yourTable. u would return 5 records .. that's 5 records regardless of nocount on or off

Comment: But the SQLDataReader property RecordsAffected doesn't return 5, it returns the wrong number.

Comment: is your sproc only limited to one statement?  ie. .select top 5 from yourTable

Comment: Again, I think we need to see the sproc to determine what's going on. I know you don't think it's relevant, but we won't have enough information to provide an answer otherwise.